# Swift Package how to link a non system static library

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I can't seem to find a way to link a non system static library

I tried using .linkedLibrary, but it's resulting in a error because it only works for system libraries, I also tried using unsafeFlags but I couldn't refer to the package relative path.
The static library which is .a file exists in the package itself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.